# How can I mount Microsoft OneDrive as a network drive in OSX?

Tags: macos, file-sharing, microsoft

I have a 50GB OneDrive account which is basically full.

I'd like to store/access stuff directly on/from my OneDrive by mounting as a network share, rather than syncing with my Mac, and therefore using up 50GB of Mac HDD space.

This is [possible on Windows](http://www.guidingtech.com/42273/map-onedrive-network-drive/), and I can confirm this works on my OneDrive account.

On Mac, I try the equivalent, e.g.:

[image]

This correctly asks for credentials:
[image]

But then fails:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: As an possible option, have you looked at using [OneDrive](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/onedrive/id823766827?mt=12) from the App Store?  Or [App Drive for OneDrive](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/app-drive-for-onedrive/id989074239?mt=12)

Comment: I'm pretty sure these only allow you to sync your OneDrive with your Mac (thus using up disk space on the Mac). I'm looking to mount the OneDrive instead, so it doesn't use up Mac HDD space.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot mount a remote "drive" to OneDrive as the synchronization/authentication  protocol is not implemented within the OS X file system.  (It is in Windows, which is why can you do it).

However, I have a client who accomplished this with an App:  [CloudMounter](http://mac.eltima.com/mount-cloud-drive.html).  It worked really well and was priced pretty fairly ($30).

I personally don't have a need for this software so I don't use it (I am also not affiliated with this company in any way).  However, I can tell you that it has worked very well for my client and he has no issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your not the only one with this problem, actually I think it isn't supported by Microsoft, personally I use [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/apps/expandrive/), an app focused on creating virtual drives for cloud services.

Hope this helps,

Tiferrei

Comment: It is supported by Microsoft.  It works perfectly on Windows 7 by adding as a network share using info at the link...and no need for extra software...

Comment: Yes, but I read on a Microsot forum, it isn't supported on Mac and there are only some lucky users who can make it work on windows 8 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try Browsing to your onedrive from a web browser. then click into any directory. Once in there look at the URL and copy the numbers and letters after id= to the % sign. Then add that at the end of https://d.docs.live.net/xxxxxxxxxx for an example. That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround to this, of course, is to simply save cloud-based documents directly to your mounted iCloud Drive, then copy from there into your OneDrive. OneDrive doesn't care where those files reside, so it thinks iCloud is just another locally mounted volume.

Answer (score -3):

If you use MSOffice on the Mac, it will allow you to set OneDrive as default file location. When opening or saving files, you can select any folder in your OneDrive account without the need for a local copy as iCloud does. That should Apple do with iCloud too.